# Need help with Google chrome certificate transparency settings

Tags: security, google-chrome

I'm following [this guide](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#CertificateTransparencyEnforcementDisabledForUrls) to disable cert transparency policy for certain domains.

So I modified the `~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist`, and confirmed it with

```
%> defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist
{
    CertificateTransparencyEnforcementDisabledForUrls =     (
        "static.lufaxcdn.com"
    );
```

However it's not effective.

Maybe I've modified the wrong file? Anyone knows?

You can test with the following sites:

```
https://static.lufaxcdn.com/wcm-images/Qq2ftUycGETXm3-lLP4KNg.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I need to quit and restart Chrome, which is not mentioned in the document, sigh.

I also need to wait for ~1 minute, simple quit and restart may not work immediately.